# .bcf file missing causes a separate error?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, texmaker, jabref

I am using `backend=biber` in my preamble of the main thesis file to create my bibliography. To compile the references I used JabRef in `biblatex` mode. I am using Texmaker 5.0.3 editor.

MWE

```
   \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}

    \usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
        {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage[polish, english]{babel}
    \usepackage{enumitem} % listing package
    \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0394}{\ensuremath{\Delta}}


    %Referencing Style
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks = true, citecolor = blue} % recolors hyperlinks

    \usepackage
    [backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-comp,
    citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
    maxcitenames=2, % sets limit for et al in citations
    maxbibnames=99, % frees up limits to authors listed in references
    giveninits=true, % initialise each author
    sorting=nyt, % sort by name, author and publication title
    sortcites=false,
    hyperref=true]{biblatex} % citation hyperlinks

    \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
    {\enumerate{}
        {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
    {\endenumerate}
    {\item}

    %Corrections to referencing style

    \DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{{#1}} % * clears formatting of publication titles
    \DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot} % italicised journal titles
    \DeclareFieldFormat*[inbook]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}\isdot} % italicised journal titles

    \renewbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
        \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
             \printfield{volume}%
             \printfield{number}%
         \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
             \printfield{eid}} % changed volume-number-pages layout

      \renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addcomma\space}}% colon between volume numbers and pages
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}} % parentheses around volume number

       \DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace} % parentheses bracket around Ed.

    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % puts given names after surname
    \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "normal" citation commands
    \DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the articles within bibliography
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}%emboldens volume #
    \renewbibmacro{in:}{}

    \newcommand{\biband}{\ifcurrentname{labelname}{\bibstring{and}}{\&}} % changes citation 'and' to ampersand
    \renewcommand*\finalnamedelim{ \& } % references delimiter becomes ampersand
    \renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space} % adds comma between cited author and year
    \renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} % semicolons instead of commas between same author citations


\addbibresource{Bib/References.bib}

    %Paragraph indentation
    \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
    \hypersetup{urlcolor = blue}
\printbibliography[title=References]

\end{document}
```

When I run a BibTex function in TexMaker set to biber in order to place it into the main `Thesis.tex` document, I get the following error.

> Process started
>
> INFO - This is Biber 2.13 INFO - Logfile is 'References.blg'
>
> ERROR - Cannot find 'References.bcf'! INFO - ERRORS: 1
>
> Process exited with error(s)

I looked into the directory and indeed there are no `.aux` or `.bcf` files. I figured somehow they got deleted when I was having the folder synced over Google Drive (strangely so.. didn't do it any time until now).

Can anyone advise how to recover/regenerate those files? I suspect they're causing further headaches when performing Quick-Build on the main `.tex` file as well which does not work either anymore.

Thanks,

Comment: The `.bcf` and `.aux` file are automatically created by a LaTeX run (the run should end without errors to make sure that the files are usable). So you have to compile your document with LaTeX before you can run Biber/BibTeX. Note that you **run Biber/BibTeX on the file name of your main `.tex` file and *not on the `.bib` file***. Assuming your `.tex` document is called `Thesis.tex` you ran `pdflatex Thesis`, `biber Thesis`, `pdflatex Thesis`, `pdflatex Thesis`. In your editor the main `.tex` file must be in focus, not the `.bib`.

Comment: For more details see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864

Comment: `@moewe`

I will ask a separate question about this, cannot provide the code I get when I run the `LaTex` command. In essence it seems there are spurious `}` after the `.tex` file executes `\printbibliography`. Unsure how to proceed right now.

Comment: OK, since you asked a new question it is probably best to close this question here as a duplicate of the standard 'why and how do I need to run Biber/BibTeX' question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 do you agree?

Comment: Sure - I would appreciate your input on the issue here, this is the code resulting from running the `LaTex` command on the `.tex` file. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506719/argument-ot1-has-an-extra